# How to Show SpeedMeter on Screen in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added Speedmeter to my project but it doesnt work. Just stays in 0. I completely new in C#. Project is 2D. Here is code;

```
public Text text;
private double Speed;
public float speed0 = 0;

void Start()
{
    text.text = Speed.ToString();
    startingPosition = transform.position;
}
Vector3 startingPosition = Vector3.zero;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    speed0 = ((transform.position - startingPosition).magnitude / Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    startingPosition = transform.position;

    text.text = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude + " km/h ";


}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the point of all the other code when your display is only `text.text = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude + " km/h ";`?

Comment: I dont know exactly, I just did saw other people's answer and tried to create something, but didnt work.@UnholySheep

Comment: do you get any errors in the console? Does your objects have a Rigidbody2D attached? Is this Rigibody2D actually the component moving your object? E.g. it won't have any velocity if you have broken the physics by moving your object via `transform.position = ...`, `rigidbody2D.position = ...;` or even `rigidbody2D.MovePosition(....);` .. since in all these cases you have never applied a velocity to the `Rigidbody2D` component

Comment: Nope, there is no errors. And yes my object has Rigidbody2D. @derHugo

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude` with the unused variable `speed0`

Answer (score -1):

This is all the code you need to have the text represent the speed on the x-axis in real time.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class NewBehaviourScript1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text text;
    [SerializeField] GameObject cube;
    [SerializeField] float speed;

    Rigidbody cubeRb;

    void Start()
    {
        cubeRb = cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var deltaSpeed = Mathf.Abs(cubeRb.velocity.x) * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        text.text = deltaSpeed + " km/h ";
    }
}
```

The speed variable allows you to tweak the km/h indicator to your preferences.

Use TMPro package when you do anything text-related. It adds more flexibility and everyone uses it.

[SerializeField] is the same as making your variables public, with the extension that they belong only to this class. It's a standart to not declare them as public.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: What? What is the `speed` supposed to be? Where should it come from? And why do you think you need `Time.deltaTime` here? The `cubeRb.velocity` already **is** in units per second anyway...

Comment: @derHugo If I wish my speedometer to show 3x the speed, but still cover the same distance in-game, it won't be possible without a variable like `speed`. It's not mandatory, but highly preferable as far as I can tell. It comes from your own preferences as mentioned in my post. And regarding Time.deltaTime, you're right it's not needed.

Comment: OP doesn't mention anything about waning to be able to multiply the given actual velocity by a value ... so I'm not sure why you would introduce this additional level of complexity ... and if you look at the question OP is already using `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude` .. so if this returned `0` for them why should your code behave differently?

Comment: @derHugo I appreciate your feedback, even though unsolicited. I've already tested my answer and it does solve the problem of OP. I'm sure a developer with your experience will most definitely have comments on how to improve code so If in the future I am the one posting a question I'll gladly appreciate your input. Take care! :)